# how to add dropdown icon in android?

Tags: android, layout, drop-down-menu

I have a dashboard layout ,Now i am need to add "dropdown icon" on this layout, In this dropdown contains three sub items(All,Event,Invitation)i am tried below code to add dropdown_icon..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appmunu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="ringee.app.com.ringeeapp.UserDashBoard">

     <item
        android:id="@+id/dropdown"
        android:icon="@drawable/dropdown_icon"
        android:title="Dropdown"
        appmunu:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/all" //dropdown item1
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="All"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/event" //dropdown item2
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Event" 
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/invitation" //dropdown item3
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Invitation"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/create_occasion" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_event"
        android:title="Create Occasion"
        appmunu:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/account_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/profile_image" />


</menu>
```

when i am using above code the "create occasion" icon is not shown(in that place the dropdown icon is overrided) and create occasion added with profile_image and account_setting list.So my need is added dropdown icon on dashboard along with create_occasion icon,How can i achieve this please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach by putting text View on toolbar and show popup window on clicking that text View

On Clicking your Text View

```
@OnClick(R.id.product_item_quantity)
void onQuantityButtonClick(View view) {
int offY = textView.getHeight();
quantityPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, getPopUpXOffset(), -offY);
}
```

set this on your onCreate view

```
private void setPopupWindow() {
// adding a view tree observer on main container
mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver
        .OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        // remove predrawlistener
        mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        setPopUpParams();
        return true;
    }
});

textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver
        .OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        // remove predrawlistener
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        setPopUpParams();
        return true;
    }
});
}

private int getPopUpXOffset() {
return -getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_width_offset) / 2;
}
```

to set the popup parameters

```
private void setPopUpParams() {
if (textView.getWidth() == 0) {
    return;
}
// item what you want to show.
item = getArguments().getParcelable(ARGUMENT_PRODUCTS);

int popWidth = quantity.getWidth();
int popHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.color_size_popup_height);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
View popUpLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.textView_popup, productScrollView, false);

final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popUpLayout);

final TextViewAdapter adapter = new TextViewAdapter();
adapter.setMaximumViews(item.getTextViews());

ListView textViewList = (ListView) popUpLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_View);
textViewList.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setPopupRowClickListener(new TextViewAdapter.OnPopupRowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int position) {
        int textViewSeleted = item. getTextViews();
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        textView.setText(adapter.getItem(position) + "");
    }
});

setPopUpParams(popHeight, popupWindow, popWidth);

this.popupWindow = popupWindow;
}
```

on your array adapter

```
public class TextViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private int maximumTextView;
private int selectedItem = -1;
private OnPopupRowClickListener popupRowClickListener;

public TextViewAdapter() {
    super(YourApplication.get(), R.layout.row);
}

public void setPopupRowClickListener(OnPopupRowClickListener popupRowClickListener) {
    this.popupRowClickListener = popupRowClickListener;
}

public void setMaximumTextView(int maximumTextView) {
    this.maximumTextView = maximumTextView;
}

public interface OnPopupRowClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(int position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return  maximumTextView - 1;
}

@Override
public Integer getItem(int position) {
    return getNumberAtPosition(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(YourApplication.get());
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.textView_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    bindView(viewHolder, position);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public void bindView(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.textViewTitle.setText("" + getNumberAtPosition(position));
    viewHolder.textViewTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            QuantityAdapter.this.selectedItem = position;
            if (popupRowClickListener != null) {
                popupRowClickListener.onItemClicked(position);
            }
        }
    });
    viewHolder.textViewTitle.setChecked(position == selectedItem);
}

private int getNumberAtPosition(int position) {
    return position + 1;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.textView_title) CheckedTextView textViewTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dropDownListView directly on toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <DropDownListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: there is no possibility to add code for dropdown icon in menu item code that i was posted?

Comment: you can show drop down on clicking menu icon as PopupWindow showAsDropDown

Comment: i have a doubt..when i am onclick dropdown icon ,i need to show these(All,Invite,Event) list items...by using this code may i  achieve that ?

Comment: i am used your code ,but i need to show dropdown list items(All,Invite,Event)  when onclick dropdown icon please suggest me another code.